# VS 2010 - is there a way to implement a pop-context button, similar to what was available in vs 6

Tags: visual-studio-2010, customizing

The context is this.

I have right clicked on a function name and gone to definition.

I have examined the information there and which to return to my previous source file/position.

In vs 6, the browse toolbar contained a pop context button that would do this job.

I am looking for a way to replicate that functionality.

Thanks

Evil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keyboard shortcut that I use is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>-</kbd>.

In the menu, you can find it at View -> Navigate Backward.

Comment: Thank you. It is obvious in hindsight.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but is still very relevant and has a better solution.

The problem with Navigate Backward (previous answer) is it takes you back to *any* previous navigation whether by Go to definition, mouse, PgUp, PgDn, etc.

Popping the browse context is different, and navigates you back to where you originally requested the Go to definition or any of the other browse operations, regardless of any other navigation you did since.

The Pop Context keyboard shortcut is Ctrl+(* on the numeric keypad).
I like to make a button for it -
steps are as follow

- go to customise for the toolbar
- add/remove buttons
- Add command
- choose view -> Pop browse context.